# Enter-PSSession doesn't execute command on remote computer

Tags: windows, powershell

I want execute some of powershell comand on remote computer. My ps1 file is contain below data:

```
$secure_password = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$credential_object = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'administrator', $secure_password 
$new_session = New-PSSession -Credential $credential_object -ComputerName  192.168.1.222
Enter-PSSession $new_session
{
  mkdir "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\new_folder"
}
Exit-PSSession  
Remove-PSSession $new_session
```

I want make a directory in my remote computer that ip is 192.168.1.222 but unfortunately doesn't make directory in remote computer.
Why doesn't it work?

Comment: When using `Enter-PSSession`, you're entering an interactive session that needs manual input. Create the folder using `Invoke-Command`: `Invoke-Command { mkdir ... } -Session  $new_session`, or use the UNC path.

Comment: Why not use `Invoke-Command`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You create PSSession when you want to execute multiple commands on a remote system. However, if you only need to run a single command/script, no need for a persistent PSSession.

You use `Enter-PSSession` for **interactive** work. However, when you using PSSession in a script/function, simply use `Invoke-Command` instead. It will be easier and faster.

**Example**

```
$secure_password = 'password' | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential -ArgumentList 'administrator', $secure_password 

Invoke-Command -ComputerName 192.168.1.222 -Credential $cred -ScriptBlock { New-Item -Name "C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\new_folder" -ItemType Directory }
```

*Note: It is a bad idea to hardcode clear-text passwords into your scripts. Have a look at a native way to store credentials externally: [SecretManagement](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/secretmanagement-and-secretstore-are-generally-available/)*

Comment: Or `invoke-command $new_session { mkdir whatever }`.  Although I only use sessions for copying files.